# Finding $\lim \limits _{x\to 1}\frac{3^\frac{x-1}{4}-1}{\sin (5(x-1))}$, without l'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits

> Evaluate$$\lim \limits _{x\to 1}\frac{3^\frac{x-1}{4}-1}{\sin (5(x-1))}.$$

I first tried substituting $\frac{x-1}{4}=a$, to which I got $\lim \limits _{a\to 1}\frac{3^a-1}{\sin (20a)}$. Tried substituting again with $n=3^a-1$, but couldn't get any decent results. Can someone
give me a tip?

Comment: What if you write $\frac{3^a-1}{\sin(20a)} = \frac1{20} \frac{3^a-1}{a} \big/ \frac{\sin(20a)}{20a}$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $a^x-1\sim x \log(a)$, it implies that $3^{\frac{x-1}{4}}-1\sim\frac{x-1}{4}\log(3)$ So
$$\frac{3^\frac{x-1}{4}-1}{\sin (5(x-1))}\sim \frac{\log(3)\frac{x-1}{4}}{\sin (5(x-1))}=\frac{\log(3)}{4\cdot 5}\frac{5(x-1)}{\sin (5(x-1))}\to\frac{\log(3)}{20}$$ as $x\to 1$ since $x\sim \sin(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x-1$, hence your limit is equal to:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{3^{\frac{t}{4}}-1}{\sin (5t)}$$
Now recall that $\frac{\sin u}{u} \to 1$ as $u \to 0$ and $\frac{3^z-1}{z} \to \log 3$ as $z \to 0$ (try to use these limits multiplying and dividing by the same quantities).

Comment: You’ve missed out on an additional factor of 4 in the denominator of the log 3 limit. It should be 4log 3

Comment: @insipidintegrator You are right, thanks! I edited.